# The datediff function resulted in an overflow. How to handle using Datatype

Tags: sql-server

I am using bigint to handle to `datediff` function in milliseconds.
How to handle Using datatype

I am using  stored procedure

```
alter function [dbo].[date2timestamp] (@dateStr char(255)) returns bigint as

begin

  return convert(bigint, datediff(microsecond, '01-01-1970 00:00:00',@dateStr))

end
```

The datediff function resulted in an overflow. The number of dateparts separating two date/time instances is too large. Try to use datediff with a less precise datepart.

Comment: Why are you using a `char(255)` for your parameter? Why not a date and time data type? What *date* value is *exactly* 255 characters long?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a couple of issues here. Firstly, your input parameter is wrong; it should be a date and time value (I'm going to assume a `datetime2(7)`).

Also if you need a `bigint` then use `DATEDIFF_BIG`, which returns a `bigint`; it's no good converting an `int` to a `bigint` if the `int` has already overflowed:

```sql
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[date2timestamp] (@Date datetime2(7))
RETURNS bigint
AS
BEGIN

    RETURN DATEDIFF_BIG(MICROSECOND, '19700101', @Date);

END;
```

If, however, you aren't using SQL Server 2019+ I don't recommend using a scalar function either. Switch to an inline table value function:

```sql
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS [dbo].[date2timestamp]; --As you can't ALTER function from scalar to table value
GO
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[date2timestamp] (@Date datetime2(7))
RETURNS table
AS
    RETURN SELECT DATEDIFF_BIG(MICROSECOND, '19700101', @Date) AS date2timestamp;
```